# What is the C# regex format to match +- signs or space?

Tags: c#, regex

I've writing code using Regex format to search for numbers that has signs before it either: + , - or space like the following numbers :

```
(+02.00)
(-03.50)
( 00.00)
```

I'm using this format but i want to include space with +-

```
[+-]\d{2}.\d{2}
```

Please help , thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
[+\s-]\d{2}\.\d{2}
```

- Take note of `\s` in the first character class `[...]` that will match a whitespace.
- Unescaped hyphen should be at first or last position in character class.
- Also, you need to escape the dot otherwise it will match any character.

Comment: Thanks, it worked and thanks for refining the format.

Comment: Wouldn't "\s" match _all_ whitespace? I would just use the space character " ".

Comment: Sure @mevdschee, we can use `[+ \t-]\d{2}\.\d{2}` to match space or tab.